# Magic Square Java Read top of code for description

Tags: java

/** I am creating a perfect square using a 2-dimensional array. In the program, each row, column, and diagonal must be equal to each other. I need help with my **checkArrays** method. My intention for my **checkArrays** method is to check if each array is equal to each other, if one array is not equal to each other then it is not a perfect square (return false). */

public class PerfectSquare {

```
static Scanner sc;
static int[][] magicS;

/**
 * Builds perfect square
 */
public static void buildSquare() {
    magicS = new int[3][3];
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            //asks the user to input a number.
            System.out.println("Please type number for column " + (r + 1) + " and row " + (c + 1));
            magicS[r][c] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Prints perfect square
 */
public static void printSquare() {
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r += 1) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c += 1) {
            System.out.print(magicS[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

/**
 * Adds each row together
 *
 * @param r
 * @return
 */
public static int getRowSums(int r) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int c = 0; r < magicS[r].length; c++) {
        sum += magicS[r][c];

    }
    return sum;
}

/**
 * Adds each colum together
 *
 * @param c
 * @return
 */
public static int getColSums(int c) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < magicS.length; r++) {
        sum += magicS[r][c];

    }
    return sum;
}

/**
 * Adds each diagonal together
 *
 * @return
 */
public static int[] getDiaganolSums() {
    int[] sums = new int[2];
    for (int d = 0; d < magicS.length; d++) {
        sums[0] += magicS[d][d];
        sums[1] += magicS[d][magicS.length - 1 - d];

    }
    return sums;
}

/**
 * Checks to see if the sum of each row, colum, and diagonal should all be
 * the same, If perfect returns perfect.
 *
 * @return
 */
public static boolean checkValid() {
    int[] rowSums = new int[magicS.length];
    for (int r = 0; r < magicS.length; r++) {
        rowSums[r] = getRowSums(r);
    }
    int[] colsSums = new int[magicS.length];
    for (int c = 0; c < magicS.length; c++) {
        colsSums[c] = getColSums(c);
    }
    int[] diagSums = getDiaganolSums();
    boolean perfect = checkArrays(rowSums, colsSums, diagSums);
    return perfect;

}

/**
 * checks if each row, colum, and diagonal are equal to each other
 *
 * @param r
 * @param c
 * @param d
 * @return
 */
public static boolean checkArrays(int[] r, int[] c, int[] d) {
}

/**
 * The main method asks the user to input numbers that correlate to a row
 * and column When run, a 3 x 3 array of the numbers inputted will be printed.
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //allows to get info from user
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //executes the buildSquare method
    buildSquare();
    //executes the printSquare method
    printSquare();
    //executes the checkValid method
    checkValid();
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with your code ?

Comment: @Berger the problem is `checkArrays` returns a boolean, but has no code, so the code doesn't compile.

Comment: So fill it with code.

Comment: John, there's dozens of people who would love to help you. But it's much easier to give you the help you really need than it is to just write the method for you. And it's better for you too. Start by making comments in the code that say in English what you plan to do with the inputs and how to turn it into an output. Then write the code that does it. Then we can assist in the debugging.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I guess you need to add a return statement to fix the problem. It's always better to state the problem to make things easier.

Comment: You may try `return Arrays.equals(r,c) && Arrays.equals(c,d);` (see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[]))